# is it possible to make the kubernetes yaml annotation and managedFields hidden or shorter

Tags: kubernetes

After upgrade to new version of kubernetes, I found it add `annotation` and `managedFields` field config. Now the yaml file is so long that 96% of content is the two field, but I did not think I would use the field and change it, is it possible to hidden the content and make the yaml config more simpler and cleaner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you upgrade you `kubectl` client to 1.21 or newer, these fields are hidden.